# All widgets in Constraint Layout getting stuck to upper left corner in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have recently started coding in android studio. I made this design in constraint layout 2 weeks ago and I reopened the project today to do some more work on it but now all the widgets have gotten stuck to the upper left corner of the screen. I had already assigned constraints for all the widgets.
I searched for this problem and I tried using the "Auto connection to Parent " button and the "Infer" button (according to my understanding you select a widget and then click on infer and same for auto connection) but nothing seems to be working.

I have selected one widget with ID textView10 in the screenshot.

Any help will be much appreciated, Thank you!

The design template:
[image]

XML code snippet:
[image]

XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".StudentActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
        android:text="Student Details"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="37dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="37dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="27dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="27dp"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/editText8"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView9" />
```

Comment: just change your android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout with androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout. if you are not using androidx then change your project to androidx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

TRY THE FOLLOWING CODE SNIPPET

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
        android:text="Student Details"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="37dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="37dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="27dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="27dp"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textSize="25dp" 
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView9" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the tag at the top of your xml, which is:

```
android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
```

to this:

```
androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
```

and that should work!

Comment: Doesn't work directly, like @Syed Rafaqat Hussain said, I think I'll have to change the project to androidx

Comment: Oh right I forgot to mention you have to change the top *and* bottom tags. Same as the accepted answer I guess

Comment: Yes, it is the same