# How to fix buttons and text views 'sticking' to the upper left hand corner in Intellij IDEA android designer?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, button, label, android-constraintlayout

I have been facing the problem of buttons and text views always sticking to the upper left hand corner  ever since I started android development. I thought this was a problem with ConstraintLayout, but turns out nothing is different in RelativeLayout too.

I have tried setting constraints in ConstraintLayout, dragging and dropping the buttons/text where I want it to be, aligning it to the margins, but nothing works.

The answer(s) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64999124/all-widgets-in-constraint-layout-getting-stuck-to-upper-left-corner-in-android-s?rq=1) do not work for me, as my xml file already has AndroidX instead of just android tag.

Comment: share your code which you facing issue

Comment: There is no problem with the code, it is with the designer